# aws step function workflow with EMR addstep

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I had a general question about a simple design that I am working on. The use case is to have an AWS Step function workflow with an EMR Add Step State. This EMR job is a streaming job and will run indefinitely.

My question is are there any downsides to having a state machine workflow which runs indefinitely with the EMR step?
Are there any limitations from the AWS step functions itself on indefinitely running executions?
And are there any issues running with timeouts with the EMR Add step API internally, which could cause it to fail?

Please let me know. Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: Could you give more details on what do you mean by "EMR Add Step State"?  You can find information about quota here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html, look for "Quotas related to state machine executions"

Comment: AWS step function can only run for one year (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html).

Comment: Thank you for you responses!